# Stop watching a MongoDB change stream with the Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

The MongoDB Java driver explains clearly how to watch a collection and start /open a change stream, which is a ChangeStreamIterable:

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/driver/tutorials/change-streams/

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(new ConnectionString("mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019"));
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("restaurants");

collection.watch().forEach(printBlock);
```

But there is no explanation on closing the change stream, nor does the API seem to support a close operation.

Why is it not possible ? Is it not necessary, or just an oversight ?

Applies to all versions of the standard, async and reactive drivers.

Comment: Hi Phillip, did you find any solution to this problem? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: Hi @sixro, you just need to close database connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a closeable cursor out of ChangeStreamIterable.

```
MongoCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>> cursor = collection.watch().iterator();
cursor.close();
```